# Theorem 2.2.3 in Kai Lai Chung's "A Course in Probability Theory"

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Theorem 2.2.3 in page 29. Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be two measures defined on the same B.F. $\mathcal{F}$, which is generated by the field $\mathcal{F}_0$. If either $\mu$ or $\nu$ is $\sigma$-finite on $\mathcal{F}_0$, and $\mu(E) = \nu(E)$ for every $E \in \mathcal{F}_0$, then the same is true for every $E \in \mathcal{F}$, and thus $\mu = \nu$.

The author gives a proof when $\mu$ and $\nu$ are both finite. I was stuck when trying to proof the general case. Actually, it's sufficient to prove that $\mathcal{C} := \{ E \in \mathcal{F}:\mu(E) = \nu(E)\}$ is closed w.r.t decreasing sequence. Then it will be a monotone class.

I try to prove that any decreasing sequence will have finite-measured components when $n$ is large enough firstly. And try to use the result in finite-measured subset which follows from the theorem proved by the author to reach the final theorem. But both attempts failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\mu$ is $\sigma-$ finite on $(X,\mathcal F_0)$. Then there exist disjoint sets $E_n$ in $\mathcal F_0$ such that $X=\bigcup_n E_n$ and $\mu (E_n) <\infty$ for each $n$. Note that $\nu(E_n)=\mu(E_n) <\infty$.  **On $E_n$**  we have  field $\{E\cap E_n: E \in \mathcal F_0\}$ generating  the $\sigma-$ field  $\{E\cap E_n: E \in \mathcal F\}$. By the finite case we get $\mu (E\cap E_n)=\nu (E \cap E_n)$ whenever $E \in \mathcal F$. Sum over $n$ to finish the proof.